# Add item to model with name form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I have color pickers on my view that is generated in javascript in this format

```
$input = $('<input name="colorPicker" value="'+ value +'" />');
```

When I save, I retrieve the whole model by this way

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AjoutHospitalisation(string ufsCode, DateTime dateDebutCalendrier, DateTime dateFinCalendrier,
         GPL_Hospitalisation model, FormCollection collection)
```

and inside I set the model with form result

```
            if (collection["colorPicker"] != null)
            {
                model.PastilleColor = collection["colorPicker"].ToString();
            }

            Services.SvcHospitalisation.InsertOrUpdateHospitalisation(model, this.GetIntervenantId());
```

It is working well, but it seems not correct. I'll like change to have an automatic process and avoid to add FormCollection.
I have try with CustomModelBinder, but I need to rewrite all my model binding :/
Is it possible to "extend" model binder to add just some fields, or I'm complety wrong on the method to complete this goal ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :  To be more accurate here the complete partial view

```
    <div class="color">
    <label>Pastille du patient</label>
    <div class="picker"></div>
    <input id="addColorPicker" class="add" type="button" value="Ajouter" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.fn.colorPicker.defaults.colors = ['FF0000', 'FF8000', 'FFFF00', '40FF00', '0080FF', '000000'];

    function addPicker(value) {
        var $input;
        if (value != null)
            $input = $('<input name="PastilleColor" value="' + value + '" />');
        else
            $input = $('<input name="PastilleColor" />');
        $(".picker").append($input);
        $input.colorPicker({ showHexField: false });
    }

    function removePicker(value) {
        var input = value.format('input');
        var picker = value.format('picker');
        var palette = value.format('palette');
        $('#' + palette).hide();
        $('#' + picker).remove();
        $('#' + input).remove();
    }

    $(function () {
        if ("@(ViewBag.ColorPicker)" != "")
        {
            var str = "@(ViewBag.ColorPicker)".split(',');
            $.each(str, function(index, value) {
                addPicker(value);
            });
        }

        $("#addColorPicker").click(function () { return addPicker(); });
    });
</script>
```

when I submit the post I send with this method

```
    $.ajax({
    url: EasilyRelativeUrl("Hospitalisation/AjoutHospitalisation"),
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) { ... }
```

And with Fiddler I see well "PastilleColor=%23ff0000&PastilleColor=%23ffff00".

If I don't pass by setting Model with FormCollection, I have only the first PastilleColor in model.PastilleColor and not this string "ff0000,ffff00". I have this format to serialize color in SQL because I don't know how many color the customer need.

And it is working well with

```
            if (collection["PastilleColor"] != null)
            {
                model.PastilleColor = collection["PastilleColor"].ToString();
            }
```

so I need to have a "binder" if I have many fields to transform in 1 field.

Comment: Why you can't change your input name to PastilleColor?

Comment: I've try it. But it's name attribute and not id, it was not working. And Id attribute can't be set because I can have one to many color picker and it is saved inside one fields as they are coming by http request.

Comment: But actually mvc model binder compare name attribute with property name of view Model. So if you'll change name of the input to: PastilleColor and put string PastilleColor in action params it should work.

Comment: What's more you don't have to use a several parameter (one per input) to bind it automatically, but if all of these properties are in the same viewModel you can only put one parameter in controller action (MyViewModel myViewModel) and binder still shoud work. Actually this is the best and recomended way passing form values to the controller action.

Comment: If I remplace by name="PastilleColor", I retrieve only the first in model but 3 occurences are well sending (PastilleColor=%23ff0000&PastilleColor=%23ffff00&PastilleColor=%2340ff00)

Comment: And when the view is show, I have any color picker, it is field added by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could create some `viewmodel` class and keep it simple

```
public ActionResult AjoutHospitalisation(MyViewModel model)
{
var color=model.colorPicker;
}
```

In Javascript Ajax

```
$input = $('<input name="colorPicker" value="'+ value +'" />');

var viewModel={};
viewModel.colorPicker='somevalue';
$.post(url,{data:JSON.Stringify(viewModel)}, function(result){

});
```

If you normally post your form please make sure you have the name of the input control that matches the ViewModel property. i.e `colorPicker`